# Autostart qbittorrent on Raspbian PIXEL (LXDE)

Tags: raspbian, qbittorrent

I'm trying to do something very simple that yet I still cannot achieve after a few days of researching and trying.

In essence I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster latest version (10), with the default PIXEL (LXDE) desktop manager. When I turn on the Raspberry I want qbittorrent to open up as well (the GUI version), as simple as that.

I did create a batch file with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/qbittorrent &
```

and I've set it to be executable by anyone. Double clicking the file it opens a window asking me if I want to execute or execute in a terminal. Both options will open qbittorrent just fine.

Amongst all the things I've tried here's a brief list:

- rc.local: added line sudo bash /usr/bin/qbittorrent
- rc.local: added line sudo -u pi /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/qbittorrent
- rc.local: added line sudo -u pi /usr/bin/qbittorrent
- /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart: added the line @sh /home/pi/Documents/qbittorrent.sh
- copying the sh file to /etc/init.d

None of this has worked. To add insult to injury, whenever I google again something on the like of `Raspbian run program on startup`
I find either whatever I've tried already or, more commonly, just other people saying *Use Google duh*

I wouldn't please mind a help here and please, bear in mind that I did use Google, extensively, and I have no idea why nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed it, it was simply a matter of modifying the correct autostart file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

then add to it

```
@qbittorrent
```